# A Question about LockSupport.getBlocker(Thread t) in Java

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

> ```
> LockSupport.getBlocker(Thread t)
> ```
>
> Returns the blocker object supplied to the most recent invocation of a park method that has not yet unblocked, or null if not blocked.

Why do the printouts in this code output different objects? Have I misunderstood `LockSupport.getBlocker(Thread t)`?

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Object lock = new Object();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
        System.out.println("sub thread lock = " + lock);
        LockSupport.park(new Object());
    });
    t1.start();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    Object getBlocker = LockSupport.getBlocker(t1);
    System.out.println("main thread blocker = " + getBlocker);
    System.out.println("is blocker same ? " + getBlocker == lock);
    LockSupport.unpark(t1);
    t1.join();
}
```

Output:

```
sub thread lock = java.lang.Object@6edf6345
main thread blocker = java.lang.Object@77459877
false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LockSupport.park(new Object());
```

You're parking with a brand new object. Park with `lock`.

```
LockSupport.park(lock);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of the `LockSupport.getBlocker(Thread t)` method is correct. However, your usage is probably wrong, because you have passed a object different from `lock` in the `park` method.

For your check to return true, pass `lock` object to `park` method.

`LockSupport.park(lock);`

For this to work, you might have to make your `lock` object `final`.